# Count all point in geo polygon (sql server 2014)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table that holds alot of location that is mapped using geo polygons

And then I have another table with properties that has a location that is a "geography" property

If I use this code I get the number of properties in a specific location:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Property 
WHERE [Status] = 1 
AND Location.Filter(Geography::Parse('POLYGON ((8.476 40.2591,8.4618 40.241,8.4787 40.2403,8.4851 40.2539,8.476 40.2591))')) = 1
```

But the issue is that I what to know how many properties that is located in every location (the polygons used in my query is from the location table)

The only connection between the tables are the location point

I really needs some help here

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Ben I finally got it to work, here's the code that works for me :)

```
    SELECT location.Id, (SELECT COUNT(property.Id) FROM Property AS property WHERE property.Location.Filter(Geography::Parse('POLYGON ((' + location.GeoPolygon + '))')) = 1) AS PropertyCount 
FROM Location AS location
```

Comment: This sounds like a good use case for [STContains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933904%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks friend. Can you please explain how to implement STContains to my problem? I've never used the function and I don't understand how I should connect the two tables

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT l.LocationID, count(*)
FROM dbo.Location as l
JOIN dbo.Property as p
   on l.geoColumn.STContains(p.Location) = 1
```

I'm assuming a structure on your `Location` table of something like:

```
create table dbo.Location (
   LocationID int,
   geoColumn geography,
   …
)
```

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you for your answer, but unfortunately my geoColumn is a varchar(MAX) so when I run the code I get this error: "
Cannot call methods on varchar(max)."

Comment: Correct. Since you could have literally anything in a varchar column, it doesn't make sense to treat it as a geography type. But, if you are actually storing WKT, you could add a persisted computer column that is a geography type and then this will work. If not... what *are* you storing in there?

Comment: Hi again Ben, in the geoColumn I store the geo polygons in plain text, here's an example: 1.4749 42.6622,1.4241 42.6067,1.3987 42.5404,1.4363 42.533,1.4574 42.5093,1.3953 42.4944,1.4186 42.4832,1.4365 42.4356,1.5491 42.4235,1.5862 42.4559,1.6507 42.464,1.6768 42.4822,1.7249 42.5005,1.788 42.5774,1.7413 42.6218,1.5601 42.6622,1.4749 42.6622

Comment: That looks very close to WKT. I was able to do this just now: `declare @g geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((<the coordinates above>))', 4326); select @g` and it worked out just fine. So you should be able to define your computed column as such and you're on your way.

Comment: Nice! If you could hit the check mark next to the answer, that'll help my retirement fund. Or something like that.